# Multiple levels of indentation in quote?

Tags: indentation, quoting

I'm writing a paper that references a field in email headers called the Received field, and the Received field typically looks like this:

```
Received: from aaaa@example.com (mail.example.com [127.0.0.1])
    by majordomo@mailserver.com with SMTP id 77778888FFFF
    for <sam@mailserver.com>; Thu, 22 Sep 2011 08:44:42 -0500 (CDT)
```

I want to put this in LaTeX, inside a quote to emphasize it, but in order to get the alignment right I have to create newlines after each line:

```
\begin{quote}
    Received: from aaaa@example.com (mail.example.com [127.0.0.1]) \\
    by majordomo@mailserver.com with SMTP id 77778888FFFF \\
    for $<$sam@mailserver.com$>$; Thu, 22 Sep 2011 08:44:42 -0500 (CDT)
\end{quote}
```

What I'm wondering is how can I make the second and third lines indented one level more than the first line? I would try hanging indentations except because all three lines are treated as separate paragraphs due to the new lines it doesn't work. Is there a way I can have a different level of indentation in the first line than in the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `verbatim` environment. As an advantage you dont have to escape `<`, `>`, etc. and there is no need to insert the linebreaks manually.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Received: from aaaa@example.com (mail.example.com [127.0.0.1])
    by majordomo@mailserver.com with SMTP id 77778888FFFF
    for <sam@mailserver.com>; Thu, 22 Sep 2011 08:44:42 -0500 (CDT)
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or use the quoting package...  It allows both nesting of quoting environments and has options to treat the first line differently from the others.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[3]
\end{quoting}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quoting}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```